# How can i make a calculation in pandas on a specific column if the dataframe is multi-index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

So I have a multi index df which is organized by date (first level) and equity (second level) and then for each equity, there is a price for that equity at that date. The df looks like this:

[image: df]([![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYbDq.png)

Now the dates go from 2019 all the way to 2020.

the calculation I want to make is on the closing_price column, and the basic calculation is as follows:
(todays closing price / closing price 5 days ago) * 100

what would be a computationally efficient way of making this calculation? ive thought about using a for loop but there are over 200,000 entries so I know that would take forever.

thanks for any help you may provide.

Comment: kindly provide input and output data, not pics

Comment: Thank you for your reply. the problem Is that the code I am running is on Quantopian.com, so I dont have access to their data if I run it on my local machine. all the code I run is on their website as they provide all the data that you cant get access to otherwise

Comment: We can't cut and paste the dataframe from your picture into our shell to experiment with. You could do the same from the site you're using to run this, and format it in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With index levels called `'date'` and `'equity'`:

```
import datetime as dt 
import functools as ft
import numpy as np

the_dates = [dt.date.today(),dt.date.today() - dt.timedelta(days=5)]
data[data.index.isin(the_dates,level='date')].\
     groupby(level='equity')['closing_price'].\
     apply(lambda x: ft.reduce(np.divide,x) * 100)
```

You may need to re-sort your DataFrame if the operands need to be reversed.

Comment: Sweet dude this was the solution I was looking for. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: @T0r0nt0: you're welcome! I'm glad it helped you. Did it work right away? Or did you have to modify it at all?

Comment: The only thing I had to change was in the code where you defined `the_dates` it wouldn't let me use the subtraction sign for some reason so I just did that calculation seperate and stored it as a variable and used the variable instead. I haven't actually done anything with the data yet, as i want to understand everything in your code in case I run into any other problems moving forward.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Ok, well come back and ask more questions if you run into further issues. Happy coding to you!